# For comprehension body to execute when Lift Box[T] has Empty value

Tags: scala, lift

I'm quite happy with working with Option type in Scala, and Lift's `Box[T]` is great too.

But I'm little confused with how to dealing with Empty when it's a valid state.

For example, my program has three vals: `title`, `startDate` and `endDate`, `title` and `startDate` are required field, but `endDate` could be empty.

Now, I want get those data from database, so I wrapped them into `Box[T]`, and in the following case, `endDate` returned `Empty` which means in database it is `NULL`.

Now I want print those data on screen, so I've the following code, but it will not work because `endDate` is Empty, so the body of for comprehension will not execute.

```
import net.liftweb.common._

object Main
{
    val title: Box[String] = Full("title")
    val startDate: Box[String] = Full("startDate")
    val endDate: Box[String] = Empty

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        for (title <- this.title; startDate <- this.startDate; 
             endDate <- this.endDate)  
        {   
            println("Title:" + title)
            println("StartDate:" + startDate)
            println("EndDate:" + endDate)   // I hope now endDate = Empty or None
        }
    }
}
```

If I make `endDate` as `Box[Option[String]]`, it will works fine, but I feel it is a little ugly, because `Box[String]` should be sufficient to denote that `endDate` is NULL in database.

Comment: I know there is ``openOr("")`` could be used, but I will like to keep endDate as ``Empty`` or ``None``, because in some case empty string is valid and different from no value.

Comment: Have you considered creating an implicit from Box[T] to Option[T]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle the case where `endDate` is `Empty`, then simply don't extract it.

```
for (title <- this.title; startDate <- this.startDate) {
  println("Title:" + title)
  println("StartDate:" + startDate)
  println("EndDate:" + this.endDate)   // this.endDate == Empty
}
```

**Edit**:

If you to handle failures, just add `match..case` or `if` tests.

```
this.endDate match {
  case f: Failure =>
    // handle failure
  case endDate =>
    for (title <- this.title; startDate <- this.startDate) {
      println("Title:" + title)
      println("StartDate:" + startDate)
      println("EndDate:" + endDate)   // endDate == Empty
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but in this case, it will execute even ``endDate`` is a ``Failure``. I hope it will only execute if ``endDate`` is in a valid state(``Empty`` or ``Full``).

Comment: Added an example of how to handle a `Failure`. I'm just a little bit sad `Box` has no `isFailure` method.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I come out with this implicit conversion and wrapper class:

```
class ValidEmptyBox[T](box: Box[T])
{
    def validEmpty: Box[Box[T]] = box match {
        case Full(x) => Full(Full(x))
        case Empty => Full(Empty)
        case Failure(msg, exception, chain) => Failure(msg, exception, chain)
    }
}

object ValidEmptyBox {
    implicit def toValidEmptyBox[T](box: Box[T]) = new ValidEmptyBox(box)
}

for(empty <- Empty.validEmpty) {
    println(empty) // Empty
}

for(full <- Full("AA").validEmpty) {
    println(full)  // Full(AA)
}

for(fail <- Failure("Failure").validEmpty) {
    println(fail)  // No output
}
```

It seems works for me, but I will still like to know if there is a better way to do this.